# Algebra norm deriving from a space vector norm

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $\mathbb{A}$ be an algebra over a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, and $||.||$ be a norm on the vector space $(\mathbb{A},+,\cdot )$ which is finitely generated. We define $N:\mathbb{A}\to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ as follows :
\begin{equation} N(x)=\sup_{||a||=1} ||a\times x||\end{equation}
We need to show that $N$ is an algebra norm, meaning it verifies the three axioms of a usual norm, in addition to the property that $N(xy)\leq N(x) N(y)$.
First, I need to show that $N$ is well-defined, meaning that the set $\{ ||a\times x|| \, / \, ||a||=1\}$ is bounded, which I don't see directly how.
For the three axioms, they're pretty direct. If $N(x)=0$, then for all $a$ such that $||a||=1$, $a\times x=0$, and using $a=\frac{1_{\mathbb{A}}}{||1_{\mathbb{A}}||}$, we get that $x=0$. Homogenity and the triangle inequality are pretty clear to me.
On the sub-multiplicativity of $N$, I am stuck too as we need to prove that :
\begin{equation} \sup||axy|| \leq \sup||ax||\sup||ay|| \end{equation}
It doesn't look clear to me how I can prove this, I feel that I am missing something.
Also I feel like we need to use the fact that $\mathrm{dim}(\mathbb{A}) < +\infty$.

Comment: Is $\Bbb A$ assumed to be finite dimensional?

Comment: @Berci Yes, the vector space $\mathbb{A}$ is finitely generated.

Answer (score 2):

$N(x)$ is simply the operator norm of the linear map $R_x:=a\mapsto ax$.
Assumed that $\Bbb A$ is finite dimensional, this map, as any linear map, is *bounded*, meaning it has finite operator norm. (Explicitly one can find an upper bound using any (normalized) basis.)

The other inequality then follows by the submultiplicativity of operator norms: using that $R_{xy}=R_y\circ R_x$, we get
$$\|R_{xy}\|=\|R_y\circ R_x\|\le\|R_y\|\cdot\|R_x\|\,.$$

Comment: Isn't there a more elementary proof? I still didn't study operator norms in my course.

Comment: For the submultiplicativity: assuming $ax\ne0$, we can consider $b:=\frac{ax}{\|ax\|}$ and with that $\|axy\|=\|ax\|\cdot\|by\|\le N(x)\cdot N(y)$. Btw, we assumed *associativity* here, though it was not mentioned in the post.